# Qt - widget - update

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

I am having a widget with a push button. I want, for every click on the push button one label should be added  in the widget. I am giving the code below, but is not working. I don't know why. Somebody help me?

```
class EditThingsWindow:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QPushButton * add;

public:
    EditThingsWindow();

public slots:
    void addButtonClicked();
};

EditThingsWindow::EditThingsWindow():QWidget()
{
    QWidget* wid = this;
    wid->resize(400,400);

    add=new QPushButton(wid);
    add->setText("Add");
    add->move(20,10);
    line=new QLineEdit(wid);
    line->move(30,50);

    QObject::connect(add,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(addButtonClicked()));
}

void EditThingsWindow::addButtonClicked()
{
    QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
    label->move(200,160);
    label->setText(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
 }
```

Comment: I tried it in action. It works.

Comment: @Max
 as Fred said(below), after I called label->show(), it is working fine.

Comment: Note; You do not need to call .show() to make the widget appear, if it is to be 'embed' in another window. Instead, make sure that you add your Window as a parent parameter when instantiating your new widget. Calling .show() without having a parent widget will result in a floating widget in a new window. (Just had the same issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new QLabel is indeed added to the EditThingsWindow every time you click on the button. However, since the labels are not placed in a layout, and they are all moved at the same position with the same text (hence the same size), they all appear on top of each other, and you can only see the top one, which is probably why you think they are not being added.

Add a layout to the EditThingsWindow widget, and add each new QLabel to the layout, and you will see all the labels appear.

Comment: The situation is worse than you said. According to you at least one label should be shown. But I didn't see any label.

Comment: @prabhkaran: try calling label->show() in the addbuttonClicked() method. A newly created widget might not be automatically visible if not inserted into a layout.

Comment: You are correct. After I called label->show(), it worked. Thank you man.

Answer (score 2):

Just add layout and place your newborn labels into it.

```
 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout; // or some another QLayout descendant
 layout->addWidget(newWidget);

 widget->setLayout(layout);
```

the only place I had to change is add layout into Widget and then

```
void EditThingsWindow::addButtonClicked() 
{
    QLabel * label=new QLabel(this);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    label->move(200,160);
    label->setText(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
}
```

got things done.

If you MUST (you don't!) mess with absolute positioning, you should do all these boilerplate  code by yourself. Headers and includes omitted.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    EditThingsWindow w(0);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

EditThingsWindow::EditThingsWindow(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
i = 0;
setGeometry(2, 2, 400, 400);
add=new QPushButton(this);
add->setGeometry(2, 2, 100, 20);
add->setText("Add");
add->move(20,10);

QObject::connect(add,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(addButtonClicked()));
}

void EditThingsWindow::addButtonClicked()
{
QLabel * label=new QLabel(this);
label->setGeometry(10, 30 + i* 30, 50, 20);
i++;
label->setText(";;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
label->show();
}
```

Comment: I want to put the label where ever I want. But if I use any layouts, then, I have to lose that choice. Because Horizontal layout will put the widgets in horizontal way, and vertical layout will put widgets in vertical way

Comment: @prabhakaran Then, if you need not to use layouts (VERY strange, because you then must handle absolute position of every control after every form position/size change). Layouts are flexible and powerful, you should learn them.
But. If you want to mess with absolute pos, then: label->move(10 + i* 30, 10), i = {1, 2, 3} :) It works:)

Comment: @prabhakaran I modified your example, it works with absolute positioning, but again, read about layouts, they are extremely powerful and there is no (almost :) ) app layout (sorry) you can't achieve with them.

Comment: @prabhakaran: You can use a QTableLayout or create your own one too. If you work with absolute positions, you will have to manage window resizing or forbid resizing.